# twitch js count the number of gift subscriptions

Tags: node.js, twitch

I am making a bot for the twitch platform, and now I have reached gift subscriptions, now I have the following command:

```
client.on('subgift', (channel, username, streakMonths, recipient, methods, userstate) => {
  subGiftHandler(channel, username, streakMonths, recipient, methods, userstate)
})

function subGiftHandler(channel, username, streakMonths, recipient, methods, userstate) {
  client.say(channel,
    `Thank you @${username} for gifting a sub to ${recipient}.`
  )
}
```

It's good when they give only one subscription at a time. But when, let's say, 10 subscriptions are given, and there are 10 such messages from the bot, it will be so-so.

How can I get the number of gift subscriptions, and add this to the condition to display a different message if there are more than one subscription?

I tried `const senderCount = userstate["msg-param-sender-count"]`
but it only returns `false`.

And if `const senderCount = ~~userstate["msg-param-sender-count"]`
then it only returns `0`.

I using tmi.js

Comment: The TypeScript definition file for tmi seems to reflect what you're attempting - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4a254ca8d58c398690998cf914d708f5acc15627/types/tmi.js/index.d.ts#L214. Sounds like you're always receiving `undefined` instead of a string or number value. Though I'm curious, how are you setting up a test bed for your changes?

Comment: @Seth no i get either false or 0 if i use ~~

Comment: @Seth I give subscriptions to the channel, and so I test

Comment: Are you anonymously donating? According to these types you should be getting an integer back. Unfortunately, it's hard to help any further without having a minimal way to reproduce and test the issue.

Comment: @Seth 
no, not anonymous, regular gift subscriptions

Comment: look into tmi.js's `submysterygift` condition.  Hint: https://github.com/tmijs/tmi.js/blob/main/lib/ClientBase.js#L706